# Python - Alguma função para descobrir o ângulo tendo o valor do cosseno

Tags: python, numpy

Existe uma forma de calcular por Python, o ângulo de um triângulo retângulo, já tendo o valor do cosseno?

Por exemplo:

a² = b² + c² - 2bc.cos α (substituindo:)

3² = 4² + 5² - 2.4.5.cos α

9 = 16 + 25 - 40.cos α

9 = 41 - 40.cos α

9 - 41 = -40.cos α

-32 = -40.cos α

-32/-40 = cos α

0,8 = cos α

α = cos-¹ 0,8 (usando uma calculadora temos que:)

α ≈ 36,7º

No exemplo acima, temos que utilizar a calculadora científica e calcular o cos^-1 ....
porém gostaria de que o Python realizasse essa equação.

Alguém sabe como realizar esta equação no Python e/ou qual biblioteca devo usar?

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome dessa operação é [arco cosseno](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es_trigonom%C3%A9tricas_inversas) e ela pode ser calculada usando a função `acos` da biblioteca [Math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.acos):

```py
import math
anguloEmRadianos = math.acos(0.8)
anguloEmGraus = math.degrees(anguloEmRadianos)
print(anguloEmGraus) # Imprime: 36.86989764584401
```

Vale deixar claro que o retorno desta função é em [radianos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiano). Na sua pergunta, você parece querer o retorno em graus, e portanto no código acima fiz uso da função [degrees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.degrees) para a conversão, que também é da biblioteca Math.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!